# Upload files with React Hooks and Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, react-hooks, antd

I am trying to upload files using React Hooks and the Upload component from AntDesign. I thought it would be no problem, and I have been trying many different ways to do this using React Hooks (without Hooks, I can do it without any issue at all).

I made a simplified example here:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/upload-with-react-hooks-ant-design-1jmod?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I am sure I am doing it wrong, but it seems I am not able to find the best way to achieve this. I am always running into stale closures and I am not sure how to avoid this.

What's the problem? I don't get the file in the processRemainingFiles. Have a look in the console, after dropping a file in it. You'll get:

```
[uploadFile] undefined
```

Even though the logic seems to work here *for me*, I know there is another issue with this code: if another files is dropped, then it would start uploading instantly as well. There are many ways to go around this, but since it makes the code longer, I preferred to share something simpler.

Comment: Your codesandbox shows that it got struck at 100% and not showing any uploaded file in UI. You said that your logic is working but looks like it doesn't.  can you be more clear on what you are trying to achieve? like multi file upload with antd upload component with react hooks..is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I clarified a bit, as it's true, I didn't really tell the error I got. Now it's easy to check that code and experience the issue :) I found a different way to do what I like, but also, I would love to have this piece of code to work (because technically, I still struggle to understand where it goes wrong).

Answer (score 3):

````
    import { Upload} from 'antd';
    const Dragger = Upload.Dragger;
    
     const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<any[]>([]);
     const [FileSend, setFileSend] = useState<any[]>([]);
  

  const propsUpload = {
    onRemove: (file:any) => {
        const index = fileList.indexOf(file);
        const newFileList:any = fileList.slice();
        newFileList.splice(index, 1);

        return setFileList(newFileList)
    },
    beforeUpload: (file:any) => {
      setFileList([...fileList, file]); 
      return false;
    },
    onChange(info:any) {
      const listFiles = info.fileList.slice(-3);

      const newArrayFiles  = listFiles.map((file:any) => file.originFileObj? (file.originFileObj) : file );
      
      const anAsyncFunction = async (item:any) => {
        return convertBase64(item)
      }

      const getData = async () => {
        return Promise.all(newArrayFiles.map((item:any) => anAsyncFunction(item)))
      }
      getData().then(data => {
        setFileSend(data)
        console.log(data);
      })
    },
    multiple:true,
    fileList: fileList,
  };
 const convertBase64 = (file:File) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader?.result);
      }
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      }
    })
  }

.......................
In return method:
.......................

       <Dragger {...propsUpload}>
                <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
                     <Icons.FaInbox />
                </p>
                <p className="ant-upload-text">Clique ou arraste o arquivo para fazer o upload</p>
                <p className="ant-upload-hint">Aguarde o carregamento para realizar o upload dos arquivos.</p>
       </Dragger>```


.........................
To send files in base64, send array FileSend.
````